# Why can I only call my function with a .T?

Tags: python, scipy

So I'm building a SIQRA epidemic model simulation on Python and can't really figure out why my code only works when I add .T after calling my function in the last line:

```
# A grid of time pofloats
t = np.linspace(0, 10)

# The SIQRA model differential equations
def SIQRA(y, t, N, beta, delta, alfa, sigma, omega, 
          alfaSA, alfaIA, alfaQA):
    S, I, Q, R, A = y
    dSdt = -alfaSA * S * A - beta * S * I + sigma * R + omega * Q
    dIdt = beta * S * I - alfaIA * A * I - delta * I
    dQdt = delta * I - omega * Q - alfaQA * Q - alfa * Q
    dRdt = alfa * Q - sigma * R
    dAdt = alfaSA * S * A + alfaIA * A * I + alfaQA * Q
    return dSdt, dIdt, dQdt, dRdt, dAdt

# Initial conditions vector
y0 = S0, I0, Q0, R0, A0
# Integrate the SIQRA equations over the time grid, t
ret = odeint(SIQRA, y0, t, args=(N, beta,  delta, alfa,
                                  sigma, omega, alfaSA, alfaIA, alfaQA))
S, I, Q, R, A = ret.T
```

I know it has something to do with the matrix it creates but I can't really figure it out completely.

Comment: `S, I, Q, R, A = ret` would only be valid if `ret` was a sequence of exactly five items (this would include a matrix with a first dimension of 5).  Apparently it isn't - did you even look at `ret` to see what it actually is?  I guess it's something like a 1x5 matrix, so that its transpose is something that can validly be unpacked into five variables.

Comment: What's the error if you don't use the transpose?

Comment: odeint docs says it returns a `shape (len(t), len(y0))`.  Your `y0` has 5 terms, which is also what you are trying to unpack.  `unpack` works on the 1st dimension, hence the need  to transpose.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried looking into ret but it wouldn't even print without the .T

Comment: @hpaulj too many values to unpack. So basically I'm getting a 5x1 matrix but I need a 1x5?

Comment: "and can't really figure out why my code only works when I add .T" - well, do you understand *what the `.T` means*? When you write `S, I, Q, R, A =`, what do you suppose are the implications, for the thing that has to be on the right-hand side? How many values should it contain if you loop over it? How many values does `ret` contain if you loop over it? How many values does `ret.T` contain if you loop over it?

Comment: `t` has 10 values (linspace?),  So `ret` is (10,5).  `ret.T` is (5,10).  After unpacking each one of the 5 variables is (10,).  Verify for yourself.